# Required on Server vs Required on Client - ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

Could someone guide on how to achieve server validation of the [Required] attribute.

Why am I asking this? Microsoft's documentation describes two different behaviours of this attribute on server and client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0

How do I achieve server side validation?

View:

```html
@model Employee

<div class="container">
    <h1>Create Employee</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <form class="d-grid form-control-sm" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" asp-for="ID">ID</label>
                    <input class="col-sm-4" asp-for="ID" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ID" style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" asp-for="Name" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" asp-for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" asp-for=lastname />
                    <span asp-validation-for=lastname style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```cs
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //code to add value to list ..... List<Employee> emplist= new List<Employee>()

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(emplist);
    }

    public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        return View(emplist.Find(e => e.ID == id));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Employee emp) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", emplist);
    }
}
```

Model:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string? lastname { get; set; }
    [Range(200,5000)]public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
}
```

As of now I was able to achieve client validation, using jQuery scripts and it also works. Problem is when I remove these scripts to have the server validation, then no error comes for the required fields.

I have two required fields: `Name` (non-nullable) and `lastname` (nullable). There is no error when I submit the form with no values.

Comment: Try `<div class=" " required>` the in View for required fields

Comment: Have you tried with `[Required]` without the `AllowEmptyStrings`?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes but sadly that too does not throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't throw error , but it does return you invalid information in the `asp-validation-for` span.  The controller knows it is invalid but doesn't block it pass through the controller. You need to implement some code to just return to the "invalid span view" or go on to do more actions.
A simple test:
Student.cs

```
    public class Student
    {
        [Required]
        public string name {  get; set; }
    }
```

Controler

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Student student)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Privacy");

        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model Student
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
    <input asp-for="name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="name"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Test
[image]

Comment: Thank You @Qiang Fu. 
"The controller knows it is invalid but doesn't block it pass through the controller. You need to implement some code to just return to the "invalid span view" or go on to do more actions." -- this makes much sense